# Approach Question: Prove that $¬∃n∅ = n^+$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I wonder if I have approached this in the right way.  I'm not sure if I have interpreted the question correctly, or made correct use of the successor function.  Thank you in advance

> **Question:**   Prove that $¬∃n∅ = n^+$

My approach:

Prove that $¬∃n∅ = n^+$

(i) In other words, prove (by counterexample) that $∅ ≠ n^+$.

(ii) Let $n^+ = 1 \Rightarrow n^+ = ∅^+ \Rightarrow n^+ = ∅^+ = \{∅\}$.

(iii) But $∅ ≠ \{∅\} \Rightarrow ¬∃n∅ = n^+$.

Comment: I think the trouble in your proof begins with the parenthetical comment "by counterexample". Statements of the form "There does not exist $\dots$" are not established by giving a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is incorrect, because you assume that $n=1$. You need to assume that $n^+=\varnothing$, then conclude somehow contradiction.

For example,

1. Assume $n^+=\varnothing$, then $n\cup\{n\}=\varnothing$.
2. In particular $n\in\varnothing$.
3. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach this, resulting in a proof which is in essence the same as the one from the first answer.

In a slightly different notation, you're asked to prove $\;\lnot \langle \exists n :: n^+ = \emptyset \rangle \;$.

Let's see what we can do with $\;n^+ = \emptyset\;$ :
\begin{align}
& n^+ = \emptyset \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"basic property of $\;\emptyset\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \lnot(x \in n^+) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;^+\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \lnot(x \in n \cup \{n\}) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cup\;$; definition of $\;\{\cdot\}\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \lnot(x \in n \;\lor\; x = n) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"DeMorgan"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \not\in n \;\land\; x \ne n \rangle \\
\Rightarrow & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"choose $\;x := n\;$; $\;n \ne n\;$ is false"} \\
& \text{false} \\
\end{align}
This proves that there is no $\;n\;$ such that $\;n^+ = \emptyset\;$, or in other words, it proves the original statement.

Comment: That was great ... thankyou

Comment: So would a less detailed (but still sufficient) version of what you showed me there be - 1. Assume $n^+$ = ∅, Then n u {n} = ∅. ⇒ n ∈ ∅. But n ∉ ∅, ⇒ There is no n such that $n^+$ = ∅

Comment: @Stumpedphilosopher You're welcome. Yes, that would be sufficient.  However, I would have add one step inbetween for clarity:
\begin{align}
& n \cup \{n\} = \emptyset \\
\Rightarrow & \\
& \{n\} \subseteq \emptyset \\
\equiv & \\
& n \in \emptyset \\
\end{align}
Personally, I prefer reasoning at the logic level, since I find it harder to remember all the set laws in addition to the predicate logic rules which I'm already familiar with.